# ASMX service won't work in a MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asmx

I know there are many questions and answers on how to ignore routing so as to let an ASMX web service work in an MVC project.  However, none of them works for me.

My WebService is ~/WebService1.asmx.

None of the following works:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*url}", new { url = @".*\.asmx(/.*)?" });
routes.IgnoreRoute("WebService1.asmx/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*pathInfo}");
```

I thought the third one will allow everything.

I can access WebService1.asmx, WebService1.asmx?op=HelloWorld, but will get a 404 for the actual method WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld.

I must have missed something fundamental. What can it be?

--
A sample request:

```
POST http://localhost:64822/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:64822/WebService1.asmx?op=HelloWorld
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-Hans-CN;q=0.5,zh-Hans;q=0.3
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; InfoPath.3)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
DNT: 1
Host: localhost:64822
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: Tx=1872
```

PS: I am using the HotTowel template, if that is of any significance.

Comment: Do you get the 404 using GET or POST

Comment: You mean you have an ASMX service inside MVC project? How does that work? WebAPI would be the right answer. If you are just trying to access the webservices you can use jquery to invoke the webservice or HttpWebRequest if you are going to access it from the Action.

Comment: @DaveHogan: it fails for both GET and POST.  I have posted a sample request above.